# Servlet HTTP 500 - NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm just starting with J2E.

I got `NullPointerException` in the line:

```
if (!userName.equals("") && userName != null)
```

When I run server like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServletPath?name=test
```

It works perfectly. but not accepting null.

Whole code :

```
package org.mojservlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/SimpleServletPath")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("get method");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    String userName = request.getParameter("name");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    if (!userName.equals("") && userName != null){ 
        session.setAttribute("savedUserName", userName);
        context.setAttribute("savedUserName", userName);
    }
    writer.println("Request parameter has username as " + userName);
    writer.println("     Session paramter has username as " + (String) session.getAttribute("savedUserName"));
    writer.println("     context is " + (String) context.getAttribute(userName));
}}
```

Comment: Put the null check first.

Comment: You should read the stacktrace and try to understand the error message...

Comment: What Sotirios said, and remember that Java does [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so (after you fix your `if` conditions) when username is null the whole `if` body is skipped without evaluating `!userName.equals("")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (!userName.equals("") && userName != null)
```

Should be

```
if (userName != null &&!userName.equals(""))
```

Because First You will need to check on null.So if the `username = null` so Java will use [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and won't check the second condition.